# Form submit issues on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a form but i want to stop the form if the length of the four inputs is 0, but what i am having is that the form is submitting before it calls the e.preventDefault(). what can i do to it to ceck the form input before submitting it.

```
$('#job_in').click(function()
             //form1.submit(function(e) // testing the form input 
             {
                form1_name=$("input[data='form1_name']");
                form1_email=$("input[data='form1_email']");
                form1_pass=$("input[data='form1_pass']");
                form1_sex=$("select[data='form1_sex']");
                form1_cname=$("input[data='form1_cname']");
                form1_checkbox=$("input[data='form1_checkbox']");

                ceo_inputs_dis=[/* 0 */form1_name,/* 1 */form1_email, /* 2 */form1_pass,
                        /* 3 */form1_sex, /* 4 */form1_cname];

                 ceo_inputs_dis1=ceo_inputs_dis[0];
                 ceo_inputs_dis2=ceo_inputs_dis[1];
                 ceo_inputs_dis3=ceo_inputs_dis[2];
                 ceo_inputs_dis4=ceo_inputs_dis[3];
                 ceo_inputs_dis5=ceo_inputs_dis[4];

                 ceo_inputs_dis1=ceo_inputs_dis1.val().length;
                 ceo_inputs_dis2=ceo_inputs_dis2.val().length;
                 ceo_inputs_dis3=ceo_inputs_dis3.val().length;
                 ceo_inputs_dis4=ceo_inputs_dis4.val().length;
                 ceo_inputs_dis5=ceo_inputs_dis5.val().length;

                 /* do the check for name input */

                 if ( (ceo_inputs_dis1 == 0) || (ceo_inputs_dis2 == 0) ||
                      (ceo_inputs_dis3 == 0) || (ceo_inputs_dis4 == 0) ||
                      (ceo_inputs_dis5 == 0)
                    ) 
                    {
                        //<h6 id="alertmsg">All fields are important!</h6>
                        $('#alertmsg').text("Please all the four fields are empty");

                        /* disable the form */
                        forms=$('form');
                        form1=forms[0];

                        e.preventDefault();
                        /*form1.submit(function (e) 
                        {
                          //e.preventDefault(); 
                          return false;
                        });*/



                        /*form1.submit(function()
                        {
                            return false;
                        });*/
                    };
                });
```

Comment: what exactly is #job_in element ??

Comment: #job_in element is the submit button ...

Comment: I think you are not even passing 'e' that I presume is in use in e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Use [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event.

```
$('#job_in').submit(function() {
   ...
})
```

Or change `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` to `<button type="button">Submit</button>`. And in click event `form1.submit()`.